# Problem with sub domain not being found a records have been created

Tags: domains, dns, plesk

I have hosting on hostinguk but I have setup a  subdomain I have given it an A record for the domain which is https://api.roundtableweb.co.uk:444 But I am still getting a 404 not found I have setup the correct bindings in iis as follows.

[image]

I have also setup a record for my DNS.

[image]

But when I attempt to view the site, I still get a 404 not found the code works as have tested it and also just had a small html file as a test and that does not render either.
[image: But wHNEE]

[image]

Comment: 1) `api.roundtableweb.co.uk.` does have an `A` record in the DNS and 2) what you show as screenshots are not 404 errors, as no HTTP traffic was exchanged, it is the browser telling you it can't connect at all. It may be or not a DNS resolution issue (so do DNS troubleshooting first) or the fact you are using a non standard port (why?) which may be filtered either on your side, somewhere in between, or on the hoster side.